# jQuery each method for dynamic elements autorun

Tags: jquery, each, element, autorun

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
  $( '.detailTextContainer a' ).each(function() {
    var urlFoto = $(this).attr('href');
    var imgElement = $("<img />").attr('src', urlFoto)
                                 .addClass('dalsiFoto');

    $(this).empty().append( imgElement );   
  });
});
```

How can I run this function automatically after load page (without event). `'.detailTextContainer a'` are dynamic elements, which are loaded to page immediately after start page.

I tried this code:

```
function showImage (){
  $( '.detailFeatureDesc a' ).each(function() {
    var urlFoto = $(this).attr('href');
    var imgElement = $("<img />").attr('src', urlFoto)
                                 .addClass('dalsiFoto');
    $(this).empty().append( imgElement );
  });
};

showImage();
```

But this weren't successfully.

Thanks

Comment: See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: @Kamil Please share your `HTML` codes or anchor tag codes which load dynamicallly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function:

```
$( window ).load(function() {

      // create detailTextContainer here
      $( '.detailTextContainer a' ).each(function() {
             var urlFoto = $(this).attr('href');
             var imgElement = $("<img />").attr('src', urlFoto)
                                          .addClass('dalsiFoto');

        $(this).empty().append( imgElement );   

      });

});
```

From documentation, this will run the function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

Or you can use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

or the shorthand:

```
$(function() {

});
```

This will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your solution with .load() (in my page) is the same like my. The image element is append after click event.

And this solution is not functional, too:
`$function () {
       $( '.detailTextContainer a' ).each(function() {
          var urlFoto = $(this).attr('href');
         var imgElement = $("<img />").attr('src', urlFoto)
                                                       .addClass('dalsiFoto');
      $(this).empty().append( imgElement );   
    });
};`

Comment: This should work, but you have to create your dynamic elements before each function. Try to create them in windows load function (or document ready) before each.Without html code is difficult to provide working example.

Answer (score 0):

you should simply write function on window load function

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "document loaded" );
});

$( window ).on( "load", function() {
   //write your code is given section
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try "on" listener

```
$(document).on("click", ".detailTextContainer a", function() {
  // your code
});
```